# Rancher 1.6 port forwarding on any host forwards to host with rancher/server installed

Tags: docker, iptables, rancher

I'm stuck with a problem.

I have four hosts (1, 2, 3, 4) inside Rancher 1.6 UI. All hosts have almost the same configuration: nginx, PHP, MongoDB.

Host 1 has both rancher/server and rancher/agent up and running.
Hosts 2, 3 and 4 have only rancher/agent.

The problem is, all the port forwarding settings for nginx on hosts 2, 3 and 4 are completely ignored: all of the requests to 80 and 443 ports are forwarded to **Host 1** and I have no idea how to overcome that.

When I execute command `iptables -nvL -t nat | grep docker0` on Host 2, 3 or 4, I get the same output like:

```
104  6565 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      !docker0  10.42.0.0/16         0.0.0.0/0            ! match-set RANCHER_DISABLE_HOST_NAT_IPSET dst masq ports: 1024-65535
    0     0 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      !docker0  10.42.0.0/16         0.0.0.0/0            ! match-set RANCHER_DISABLE_HOST_NAT_IPSET dst masq ports: 1024-65535
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  10.42.0.0/16         0.0.0.0/0            ! match-set RANCHER_DISABLE_HOST_NAT_IPSET dst
    4   240 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match src-type LOCAL dst-type UNICAST
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            5.67.218.11         tcp dpt:80 to:10.42.204.73:80
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            5.67.218.11         tcp dpt:443 to:10.42.204.73:443
    1   528 DNAT       udp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:500 to:10.42.6.75:500
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:4500 to:10.42.6.75:4500
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            5.67.218.11         tcp dpt:27077 to:10.42.87.201:27017
  152 36328 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

where `5.67.218.11` is the IP address of **Host 1**.

If I stop Nginx container on **Host 1**, ports 80 and 443 disappear from the output.

How to make docker (or Rancher) use port forwarding locally on each host and not forward requests to **Host 1**?

**UPD:** I have another set of servers with the same configuration, and if I execute command `iptables -nvL -t nat | grep docker0` on some of the hosts in that set, I get another output, like:

```
2078K  132M MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
 2405  144K MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      !docker0  10.42.0.0/16         0.0.0.0/0            ! match-set RANCHER_DISABLE_HOST_NAT_IPSET dst masq ports: 1024-65535
  368  194K MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      !docker0  10.42.0.0/16         0.0.0.0/0            ! match-set RANCHER_DISABLE_HOST_NAT_IPSET dst masq ports: 1024-65535
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  10.42.0.0/16         0.0.0.0/0            ! match-set RANCHER_DISABLE_HOST_NAT_IPSET dst
10433  626K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match src-type LOCAL dst-type UNICAST
   14  4046 DNAT       udp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:500 to:10.42.216.158:500
   89  4639 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:10.42.186.151:80
   53  2856 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:27017 to:10.42.155.127:27017
    4  1240 DNAT       udp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:4500 to:10.42.216.158:4500
   58  3144 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 to:10.42.186.151:443
5907K 1412M RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

The only difference is: instead of some IP address of the Host with rancher/server entries have `0.0.0.0/0`, and everything works just fine. But I can't find out how to make another set of servers work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't found the solution of the described problem.
The only thing that helped was to move rancher/server to another server instance which solved the problem.

**!!! Don't run both rancher/server and rancher/agent on the same environment, since this may result problems with propagation of iptables to other hosts in your infrastracture with rancher/agent installed.**